# Edit IPs with Ansible

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to customize a IP adress with Ansible. For example when the remote system IP is `127.34.34.21` the DNS IP is `127.34.34.1`

The DNS IP is always the system IP but the last number is `1`. Is it possible that Ansible can do this dynamical?

Look up the system IP > Customize it > set the new IP as DNS IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: **"*Is it possible to customize an IP address with Ansible?*"**

A: Yes. It is. There are many options.

- Use *split* method and *join* filter. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        dns: "{{ ip.split('.')[:3]|join('.') ~ '.1' }}"
      vars:
        ip: 127.34.34.21
    - debug:
        var: dns
```

give

```yaml
  dns: 127.34.34.1
```

- It's possible to use the [*splitext*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) filter instead of *split/join*. For example, the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        dns: "{{ (ip|splitext)[0] ~ '.1' }}"
```

- Next option is [*ipaddr*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html#ipaddr-filter) filter. For example, the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        dns: "{{ (ip ~ '/24')|ipaddr('first_usable') }}"
```

---

Q: **"*Is it possible that Ansible can do this dynamical?*"**

A: Yes. It is. You'll have to decide which IP address to use. For example, use *ansible_default_ipv4.address*

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: ansible_default_ipv4.address
    - set_fact:
        dns: "{{ (ip ~ '/24')|ipaddr('first_usable') }}"
      vars:
        ip: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
    - debug:
        var: dns
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
  ansible_default_ipv4.address: 10.1.0.27
  dns: 10.1.0.1
```

See [setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#ansible-builtin-setup-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts). See other attributes of the variable *ansible_default_ipv4*. See variable *ansible_all_ipv4_addresses*.

Comment: That's exacly what I am looking for. Thank you! I added your last code to my playbook tasks and get `ERROR! conflicting action statements: debug, var`.

Comment: You're welcome! Mind the indentation. If you have problems update the question with the details. See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).